# How to solve "Error 13 while loading file" when using Qemu?

Tags: operating-system, qemu, kvm

I write the following bytes into a file named disk.img

```
FA 8D 36 1B 7C E8 01 00 F4 AC 3C 00 74 0C B4 0E 
BB 07 00 B9 01 00 CD 10 EB EF C3 4D 61 79 20 74 
68 65 20 66 6F 72 63 65 20 62 65 20 77 69 74 68 
20 79 6F 75 21 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
..enough zero to make the size of file 512bytes.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 AA
```

The above bytes are proper instructions and magic number that should work when loading into the boot sector. But after I executed "qemu-X86_64 disk.img", error happens.

> Error -13 while loading disk.img

Does anyone know how to solve the problem or what is the reason that might lead to this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can fill an image with just anything and expect it to work just because you have 55 AA in the correct place. Since you seem to be writing a bootloader make sure your code thinks it is executing at the correct place. It should be in offset 0x7C00 (if I remember this correctly, double check that). You set it by writing the line `[org 0x7C00]` at the top of your assembly file.

Also I'm not sure you can have only a 512 byte file. Try to make the disk image bigger than that using something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=512 count=2000` and then just copy your bootloader to the first part of the disk using dd again.

Also, you should use the `-hda` or `-fda` tags, so it would be `qemu -hda disk.img`. `-hda` means hard drive image, and `-fda` means floppy disk image.